# Can we use share volume to share docker container across different host?

Tags: linux, docker, container

What i want to achieve is to share docker container across different machine.

since docker will store container data into /var/lib/docker/container

i am thinking to have a network volume, and map "/var/lib/docker/container" from each machine to the same network volume.

```
Machine A
  |- /var/lib/docker/container  --------------------> network file volume 
                                                           ^
                                                           |
Machine B                                                  |
  |- /var/lib/docker/container -----------------------------
```

in Machine A when i do "docker run" to create container, i can see those file show up when i view from Machine B, however from Machine B "docker ps" i couldn`t see container is listed out.

is this a work-able approach?

Comment: I'm thinking it's doable, though it might be safer to do the mapping on the host file systems and then have the containers connect to what it thinks is a local file system.  This would avoid having to build NFS (or similar) into your containers.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that `dockerd` assumes exclusive ownership of the `/var/lib/docker` directory and that you will eventually endup corrupting its contents.

There is nothing in [Docker's official docs](https://docs.docker.com/) that hints to anything close to the opposite.

So, my advice is: don't mess with `/var/lib/docker` unless you know what you're doing.